# Retroactively apply a rule in Lotus Notes 8.5

Tags: lotus-notes

I have a large amount of e-mails in my inbox and I have created a rule that will take roughly half of them and move them into a folder. It is working on all new incoming mail, but how do I apply it to mail already in my inbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use an agent. More info in the Help file at "Automating Tasks Using Simple Agents".

Comment: But as I understand Agents functionality quite often disabled for users... :(